# jQuery matching pattern

Tags: jquery, forms, css-selectors

I'm trying to **validate** my inputs with jQuery before a form is sent.

This is what my input fields look like when there is **no value** inserted in the database:

```
    <input
      class="field"
      type="text"
      style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
      value="" name="input_18748_388_1257894000_"/>
```

This is what my input fields look like when there is **an existing value** inserted in the database:

```
    <input
      class="field"
      type="text"
      style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
      value=""
      name="input_18748_388_1257894000_46549876"/>
```

---

I would like to:

- Check if the value is already in the database
- Check if the user want to replace an
  existing value by nothing or zero and
  disallow it.
- Check if the user is trying to
  insert 0 in a new field and
  disallow it.

---

***Solved:***

```
  $("input[name^='input_"+var+"_']")
                .each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('name').match(/^input_\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+/)
                        && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() <= 0))
                    {
                        displayDialog("<?=_('error')?>")
                        flag_error = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
            });
    // Submit the form.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("input[name^='input_"+var+"_']")
                .each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('name').match(/^input_\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+/)
                        && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() <= 0))
                    {
                        displayDialog("<?=_('error')?>")
                        flag_error = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[name]')
    .filter (function () { 
        return $(this).attr('name').match (/^input_\d+_\d+_\d+_.+/$); 
    })
    .each (function () {
        if ($(this).val() <= 0) {
            //... raise a fuss ...
        }
    });
```

This needs to be called on `submit` or `change` as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a keydown event and check keycodes.
This example will disable space and the 0 char in input fields with the name attribute ending with '_':

```
$('input[name$=_]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 48 || key == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class "my_very_special_input" to every input element you would like to validate that way:

```
$(".my_very_special_input").change( function() {
                            if ($(this).val() <= 0) {
                                    alert('You cant delete this');
                                    flag_error = 1;
                                    return false;
                              }
                    });
```

Comment: Thats a good way to do it but unfortunately, I need to check if the name field is ending by '_' or by '_46549876' in order to know if there is already something for this field in the db. I could also match them all with $("input[name^='input_"+var+"_']")

Comment: i think you are confusing the name and the value attr, the normal user cant change the value of the name attr. and thats why you can decide the add the class

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit the [Regex Selector for jQuery Plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/). It allows code like:

```
$('div:regex(input,^input_(\d+|)+_?$)'); //just an example regex
```

Also, note that you can combine multiple attribute selectors, ie:

```
$("input[name^='input_'][name$='_']")
```