# removing all the DOM Elements with a specific className

Tags: javascript

How I can remove all DOM Elements with specific classname or element width ID's that start with a specific pattern. like (without any framework!)

```
id="selectbox1"
id="selectbox2"
id="selectbox3"
id="selectbox4"
```

Thanks

Comment: without jquery? good luck. :) It can be done, but will need lots of looping and regex. BTW - ID's should be unique to a page.

Comment: what is your objection with a framework? It will clearly make things easier and you don't have to use it anywhere else in your project if you don't want.

Comment: What's up with you guys? Have you been brainwashed with jQuery? `id's` are unique in the example (he wrote starts with). By lot of looping, you mean 1 single for loop? C'mon. It doesn't even require Regex, a single `indexOf` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use `getElementsByTagName(*)` iterate over the entire collection, check the `.className` property with a regex `/\bYourClasName\b/`   (className can have more than one class, seperated by a space)  and then also check the element's `.id` property with another regex:  `/^IDStartsWithThis/`   finally on any matches you would have to call `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

(On my way to work and in a rush, if you need more code I can supply it once I get there around 630 est)

Edit: here's the code:

usage: `removeElemIf(idStartsWith,containsClass)`. you can pass null, only the id (second param is undefined), blanks (blanks are ignored, both parameters are trimmed first). Case is insensitive for both parameters.

```
function removeElemIf(theID, theClass) { /* class => full match, id => startswith */

    checkID = !(theID === undefined || theID === null || (theID = theID.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')).length == 0);
    checkClass = !(theClass === undefined || theClass === null || (theClass = theClass.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')).length == 0);

    if (!(checkID || checkClass)) return;

    var oBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // only search the body
    var oElems = oBody.getElementsByTagName('*'); // get all the elements within body

    for (i = oElems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // loop through backwards in case of delete

        el = oElems[i]; // set current element
        found = false;  // reset flag

        if (checkID) { /* check the ID for starting with "theID", originally used indexOf but its case sensitive*/
            re = new RegExp('^'+theID,'i'); 
            if (el.id.match(re)) found = true;
        }

        if (!found && checkClass) {   /* only test class if the id doesn't match,
                                      save the regex in instances where the
                                      class names are long or many*/
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + theClass + '\\b', 'i');
            if (el.className.match(re)) found = true;
        }

        if (found) el.parentNode.removeChild(el); /* if found, remove from parent */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse through the dom tree and compare against the `className` property of each element found. Yes it's tedious, but that's how it's done. You can either traverse in a recursive fashion or an iterative one. The first is the easiest to write, but the second has much better performance.

Answer (score -1):

see this SO thread:
[jQuery matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920838/jquery-matching-pattern)

and check out [getElementsByTagName()](http://translate.google.at/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/node.htm#get_elements_by_tag_name) function

Comment: pls consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved ;-)